# TypeScript: how to tell WebStorm to use CommonJS rather than AMD

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm, amd, commonjs

I'm using WebStorm to build a Node.js app in TypeScript. When I write a "require" statement, the TypeScript compiler uses AMD. I know it by the js output with the asynchronous pattern.

How can I tell WebStorm to use CommonJS instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to say that to compiler, for example in npm

Option:

`-m, --module       Specify module code generation: 'commonjs' or 'amd'`

Example:

`tsc.compile(['test/cases/ship.ts', 'test/cases/fleet.ts'],
                    '-m commonjs -t ES5 --out test/tmp/navy.js');`

for more refer to: [TypeScript compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-compiler)

also have a look at this video: [TypeScript Modules Demystified : Internal, AMD with RequireJS, CommonJS with NodeJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0)

Comment: Thanks. In TypeScript settings in WebStorm there's a place to write command line options, so I wrote there "-m commonjs -t ES5". I saw that before it was set to "-m amd -t ES5".

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a WebStorm user myself, but I think WebStorm refers to the `tsconfig.json` file at the root of your TypeScript project for this type of compiler configuration.

[Here's the documentation for the `tsconfig.json` file.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json)

If this file doesn't already exist in your project, create one in the root of your TypeScript compilation directory.  In this file, you can tell the compiler which module system to use with the `module` parameter:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

See the link above for a more complete example of a `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. I took the other guy's suggestion, but I voted up.